# How to perform validation of multiple fields?

Tags: validation, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Recently I have faced a situation as follows:

There is a form with **three** inputs. All of them have related database properties (values).
Now: **at least one of them is required, but it can be any of them**.

What could be the smartest way (preferably following Kohana and/or ORM's guidelines) to do so?
I want this "rule" to be stored in model, not in controller.

So far I have managed to apply custom rule to all three fields, but this results in tripple error message, one for every field.

If more details are required - please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need

```
// File: application/classes/helper/validation.php
class Helper_Validation {

     public static function one_not_empty($array, $keys)
     {
         if( ! is_array($keys))
         {
             // throw new Exception('Helper_Validation::one_not_empty expects an array');
             return FALSE;
         }

         foreach($keys as $key)
         {
             // Change this IF to whatever is the required value
             if(Arr::get($array, $key) !== NULL)
             {
                 return TRUE;
             }
         }

         return FALSE;
      }
 }
```

Now apply it to all fields:

```
 $keys = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');

 $validation = Validation::factory($array)
      ->rule('field1', 'Helper_Validation::one_not_empty', array($keys))
      ->rule('field2', 'Helper_Validation::one_not_empty', array($keys))
      ->rule('field3', 'Helper_Validation::one_not_empty', array($keys));
```

I think this should work, have not tested though, let us know :)

Comment: Looks promising AND lead me on yet another way to deal with it. Thank you! I'll try your code/idea out soon and then comment once again and approve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    public function rules(){
        return array(
            'field1' => array(
                 array('at_least', array($this, 1, array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'))),
             ),
            'field2' => array(
                 array('at_least', array($this, 1, array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'))),
             ),
            'field3' => array(
                 array('at_least', array($this, 1, array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'))),
            ),
       );
   }

   public static function at_least($array, $needed = 1, $fields){
       $found = 0;
       foreach ($fields as $field){
           if (isset($array[$field]) AND Valid::not_empty($array[$field])){
               $found++;
           }
       }
       return ($found >= $needed);
   }
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/kiall/1159271)